# Equivalente italiano di "it makes sense"

Tags: word-usage, idioms

Benché sia nato e cresciuto in Italia fino all'età universitaria, abito all'estero da molti anni, e l'inglese è (da più di un quarto di secolo) di gran lunga la mia lingua di uso più frequente.

In inglese, capita molto spesso di dire "that makes sense!" nel contesto di una conversazione, anche per convalidare ciò che l'interlocutore sta dicendo. Pertanto è fin troppo naturale per me usare la locuzione "ha senso!" in contesti simili quando converso in italiano.

Ma i miei interlocutori "nativi" storcono il naso a questo tipo di locuzione, dicendo che suona innaturale. A loro opinione, va bene dire "non ha senso", ma dire "ha senso" senza altro contesto non è affatto comune nel parlare quotidiano.

La domanda è,

- Hanno ragione i miei interlocutori a sostenere che "ha senso" come intercalare in una conversazione suona innaturale?
- Se sì, qual è una locuzione alternativa che esprima lo stesso tipo di convalida dell'inglese "it makes sense"?

Comment: Dato che il "suonare bene/male" è qualcosa di soggettivo, la risposta alla domanda se abbiano ragione loro è "hanno ragione loro... per quanto riguarda loro". Io, personalmente, non trovo che suoni male (anche se, avendo vissuto per sei anni in Inghilterra, è possibile che mi suoni bene per lo stesso motivo per cui suona bene a te). Espressioni alternative possono essere "_mi sembra giusto_", "_mi sembra logico_" o anche la più idiomatica "_non fa una piega_"

Comment: Basta evitare il calco “fa senso”. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rispondo alla tua ultima domanda: *è sensato* mi sembra più comune in frasi positive.

Comment: Questo sembra più un commento che una risposta...

Comment: @abarisone A me invece sembra che molti utenti non abbiano ben chiaro cos'è un commento nel sistema Stack Exchange. Non sono un modo per dare la propria opinione velocemente o scrivere una pseudo-risposta a basso sforzo. I commenti servono, come dice il tooltip, solo "per chiedere più informazioni o suggerire migliorie" alla domanda. Questa mia frase non fa nessuno dei due, ma piuttosto cerca di dare una risposta all'OP. Ergo, è una risposta.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: È vero, un commento non sarebbe il posto per un'opinione, ma una risposta ancor meno. In un commento, per lo meno, un'opinione può essere utile, per esempio, per far venire in mente qualcosa a un altro utente che giunge così a scrivere una risposta.

Comment: Non mi torna la tua seconda affermazione: perché la stessa frase può farti venire in mente qualcosa se sta scritta in un commento ma non se sta scritta in una risposta? Inoltre, mi sembra che una risposta sia un posto migliore che un commento per un contributo di questo tipo, per vari motivi: viene ritrovato da una ricerca; può essere migliorato tramite edit; può venire votato negativamente da chi non è d'accordo e quindi meglio valutato.

Comment: Credo che il problema stia a monte: già la domada è formulata in modo da dare un così ampio spazio alla discrezionalità che, a mio avviso, rischia di ricadere nella categoria delle [domande da evitare](https://italian.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Forse una formulazione tipo "Quanto è comune l'uso di _"ha senso"_ come interiezione e quali possono essere espressioni equivalenti?" (meglio ancora se le due domande fossero state separate) avrebbe consentito risposte più oggettive e maggior chiarezza sulla distinzione tra commento e risposta.